# set source of audio tag to empty

Tags: html, html5-audio

I'm using HTML5 audio tags. I have set source to some file. and now I want to clear it.

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = "there was some file here";

//now i manually set this to empty string
audio.src = ""
```

When I debug this, this source actually gets set to the HTML file this is in and not empty string. Why is this happening and what is the right way of removing source from the tag.

Comment: I tried to replicate your problem and setting an empty string works fine. Are there any other details you can add?

Comment: did you try setting the source first? set the source first to some file by using filepicker and then clear it out.let me know if you still cannot replicate it i'll find out an exact way of doing it.

Comment: I don't know what 'filepicker' is.

Answer (score 10):

This helped me to solve this problem:

```
audio.removeAttribute('src')
```

Answer (score 0):

The empty string means an empty relative URL, which resolves to the page itself (the same way `<a href="">this page</a>` does).

As suggested by Tobi, you need to remove the attribute entirely to remove the source.